# Order by activity date instead of users followed

Tags: laravel

I have two tables, the activities table and followings table. I want to get "following" activity the date it was created instead of by the date the user was created.

```
    Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->index();
        $table->integer('activity_id')->index();
        $table->string('activity_type', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index(['activity_id', 'activity_type']);
    });

    Schema::create('followings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('follower_id');
        $table->dateTime('followed_date')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('unfollowed_date')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unique(['user_id', 'follower_id']);
    });
```

Right now I have this code:

**Controller:**

```
$followings = $user->following()->get();
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($followings->sortByDesc('id') as $following)

                        @foreach($following->user->activity->sortByDesc('id') as $activity)
                        
                        @if($activity->activity_type == 'App\Thread')
                        <li class="activity">
                            <div class="activity-user">
                                <p class="avatar" style="background-color: {{ $activity->user->color }}">
                                    {{ substr($activity->user->name, 0, 1) }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="activity-body">
                                <h4><a
                                        href="/profiles/{{ $activity->user->name }}?profile-posts">{{ $activity->user->name }}</a>
                                    published <a
                                        href="/forums/{{ $activity->activity->channel->slug }}/{{ $activity->activity->slug }}/">
                                        {{ $activity->activity->title }}</a></h4>
                                <p>
                                    {!! BBCode::parse($activity->activity->body) !!}
                                </p>
                                <p class="created-at">
                                    {{-- {{ $activity->activity->created_at->format('l') }}
                                    at
                                    {{ $activity->activity->created_at->format('h:i A') }} --}}
                                    {{ $activity->activity->created_at->format('M j, Y') }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        @endif
                        @endforeach

                        @endforeach
```

**Model:**

```
public function following()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Following::class);
}
```

Is there anyway for me to reach the polymorphic table and order by the Activity date instead of by the following() date?

Right now, it returns records based on the user's name in the date they posted it, but I would like it strictly by the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

**Controller**

```
    $followings = $user->following()->get();
    foreach($followings as $following) {
        foreach($following->user->activity as $activity) {
            $followingArray[] = $activity->id;
        }
    }
    //dd($followingArray);
    if(!empty($followingArray)){
        $following = Activity::whereIn('id', $followingArray)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    } else {
        $following = '';
    }
```

**View:**

```
                    @if(!empty($following))

                    @foreach($following as $activity)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, you will be better of with a custom `DB` query like this, I haven't tested it so you will need to adjust for your use case but basic concept for Laravel is pretty much the same.

```
$following = Following::join('users', 'followings.user_id', '=','users.id')
        ->join('activites', 'users.id', '=', 'activities.user_id')
        ->orderBy('activities.created_at')
        ->select('followings.*')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, but it actually orders by the User, instead I want the Activities in order, regardless of the user

Comment: @user123 then you need to build a custom query, check updated answer for reference.

Comment: i've also tried your query to no avail, I appreciate the assistance and your response though, and will continue to try to adjust it.